# How to return a List[User] when using sql with slick

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I can seem to get how I can return a List[User] from a raw sql query.

```
implicit val getUserResult = GetResult(r => User(r.nextInt, ....))

sql"""
select * from users where id =1

""".as[User]
```

This seems to compile fine, but if I change this to return a list and not a single result I get an error.

```
.as[List[User]]
```

Error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter rconv: scala.slick.jdbc.GetResult[List[User]]
```

How can I change the implicit GetResult to return a list?

**Update**

So I created the implicit like:

implicit val getUserResult = GetResult( r => User(r.nextInt, ....))

val query: StaticQuery0[User] = sql"....."

query.list()

I can this error:

```
[PSQLException: Bad value for type int : asdf asdfs]
```

In psql I can see that I have "asdf asdfs" in some columns, but not INT columns.  If things compile I'm not sure why I am getting this error, looks like a bug?

Comment: This query will return one `User` since it looks for `id` which I would assume is unique. You can still return this query `.as[User]` but append `Nil` like `.as[User] :: Nil`.

Comment: @goral yes I will change the query thanks, but I was trying to emphasis how to get a list of users back.   the query wasn't the focus.

Answer (score 4):

As @goral said you will probably only get one row since you filter by id, nevertheless you can easily get a list:

```
import scala.slick.driver.JdbcDriver.backend.Database
import Database.dynamicSession
import scala.slick.jdbc.{GetResult, StaticQuery => Q}
import Q.interpolation

val t: StaticQuery0[User] = 
  sql"select * from users where id = 1".as[User]

val list: List[User] = t.list()
```

`StaticQuery` has all the common methods like `list`, `first`, `firstOption` and so on, since they are inherited from the `Invoker` trait.

If you want to use a custom case class and use a `GetResult`:

```
case class User(id: Int, name: String)

implicit val getUserResult = GetResult(r => User(r.nextInt, r.nextString))

val t: StaticQuery0[User] = sql"select * from adwords_ads where name = ".as[User]
val list: List[User] = t.list()
```

Edit:

It's working for me even without the implicit mapper because the slick schema generator has already generated one for me:

```
/** GetResult implicit for fetching SalesforceLogRow objects using plain SQL queries */
implicit def GetResultSalesforceLogRow(implicit e0: GR[Long], e1: GR[String], e2: GR[Int], e3: GR[java.sql.Timestamp], e4: GR[Option[java.sql.Timestamp]]): GR[myEntity] = GR {
  prs => import prs._
    myEntity.tupled((<<[Long], <<[Long], <<[String], <<[Int], <<[java.sql.Timestamp], <<[Long], <<?[java.sql.Timestamp]))
}
```

I usually have it in a schema object, apparently you don't have it and Slick doesn't know how to map your plain SQL.

Comment: I thought I write the query using sql"select ...".as[User] and then I have to create an implicit GetResult that maps the values.

Comment: @Blankman I assumed that user was a case class describing your slick schema, if not you can always create the implicit `GetResult` and map the query results to a custom case class.

Comment: Yes I have a case class, I was just reading the slick docs and I thought for some reason I had to create this GetResult mapper again for some reason...confused sorry.  If I comment out my GetResult I get this error: ```ould not find implicit value for parameter rconv: scala.slick.jdbc.GetResult[User]```

Comment: @Blankman I made an edit, my mapper was already egnerated by the slick schema generator, I didn't know about it.

Comment: I think there is a bug, it compiles but I get this error: ```[PSQLException: Bad value for type int : asdf asdfs]```

Comment: I suppose you need to be precise with your mapper, meaning that the column order in the select must be the same as your mapper, if you select string-int your mapper must be `(r.nextString(), r.nextInt())`

Comment: Yeah I'll try that, so basically my select list has to be in the same order as my User object's constructor!